# k8s autoscaler not working, not much document to read

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling

I'm trying to setup k8s autoscaler, I went through: https://hub.helm.sh/charts/stable/cluster-autoscaler and did a lot of experiment but cannot make it work. I have two choices but both not working:

1. deploy autoscaler on master, I tried: `helm install my-release stable/cluster-autoscaler --set autoDiscovery.clusterName=hide-cluster,rbac.serviceAccount.name=default,tolerations[0].effect=NoSchedule,tolerations[0].operator="Equal",tolerations[0].value=/"true/",tolerations[0].key=node-role.kubernetes.io/master`
   but it always says the field `tolerations[0].value=/"true/"` is not as expected, I tried several possible versions I can think of, like using 'true', "true", true etc. none of them works.
2. deploy on a non-master node: it asks for network plugin in this case... I think only the master node has network plugin.

There is very very limited document about how to setup autoscaler without using kops or EKS. I also wonder how many autoscaler solution we have on the market? It seems not many learning resources online for autoscaler.

Edit: I finally make the autoscaler run following this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cluster-autoscaler.html

But it does not include EC2 instances created by ASG to nodes. I checked the log it says the ASG is already found and registered, no error or other hint I can find why no nodes shows up in `kubectl get nodes`

Comment: So where is your kubernetes cluster? Azure? on premise? eks? gke?

Comment: @paltaa It's on AWS, but I install k8s in EC2 instance and configured the cluster manually instead of using eks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like auto-scaler does not work with standalone k8s but have to use on top of EKS or Kops, although I'm not sure. really too limited resource available.

Comment: I have deployed the autoscaler through helm. Did you make it work? Its not working for me though. We were capping on CPU but it did not autoscale. I also followed this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cluster-autoscaler.html, but since its deployed through helm, i was not able to find a autoscaler deployment in my cluster

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach these instances to ASG - follow this tutorial: [attaching-instances-asg](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/attach-instance-asg.html).

Also you have to remember that instance to attach must meet the specific criteria:

- State of the instance is   `running`
- The AMI used to launch the instance still exist.
- The instance is not a member of different ASG
- The instance is launched into one of the Availability Zones defined in your ASG

> If the Auto Scaling group has an attached load balancer, the instance
>   and the load balancer must both be in EC2-Classic or the same VPC. If
>   the Auto Scaling group has an attached target group, the instance and
>   the load balancer must both be in the same VPC.

Comment: This is not my question.